# Error SQL0: The reference to external elements from the source named 'MyDatabase.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded

Tags: sql-server, dac, sqlpackage

I'm getting this error when using sqlpackage.exe, or the DacFx DLLs, to programmatically publish a dacpac (A), compiled and provided by a different team, which in turn has a dependency on another dacpac (B).

I can confirm that:

- The reference to B from A has the "Suppress Reference Warnings" to True
- The B .dacpac file is in the same folder as the A .dacpac file
- I have tried with 2 different versions of Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll, 12.0.2882.1 and 14.0.3881.1
- Both dacpacs have the setting to target SQL Server 2012, and I am attempting to publish to SQL Server 2012
- I have tried both with the `IncludeCompositeObjects` deploy options set to true, and to false

What am I doing wrong? How can I publish a dacpac that has been compiled and provided to me, which has a database reference that is referenced with a path that is invalid for me?

Answer (score 4):

This can occur when you switch between editions of Visual Studio. In my scenario, I originally built a database project using VS2017 Professional Edition. When I switched to VS2017 Enterprise Edition, I received a bunch of `The reference to external elements from the source named 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded.` errors on build (it also occurs when building in Enterprise first, then switching to Professional).

I resolved this as follows:

- Close Visual Studio;
- Delete the `*.dbmdl`, `*.jfm` and `*.user` files in the project root folder;
- Re-open Visual Studio and re-build.